# Newest AdMob SDK Download

Tags: admob

I got a message in my Admob account like this:

Have you upgraded your SDK?

On Aug. 1 2014, Google Play will stop accepting new or updated apps using the standalone Google Mobile Ads SDKs v6.4.1 or lower. Upgrade to the Google Play version of the Mobile Ads SDK to take advantage of new features, including automatic updates such as bug fixes.

Then Google is referencing this page where no downloadable zip file available: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download

Is there anyone help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From that page

> Google Mobile Ads is now offered through Google Play services. This is
>   the recommended way of enabling ads on your Android app. See the setup
>   instructions and reference docs for more details.

Use SDK Manager to dwonload Google Play Services and integrate that as it contains AdMob (along with several other services.